# Abstracting multiple data sources with one interface for the repository to use

Tags: go, repository, clean-architecture

I'm trying to apply the clean architecture, and among other things, I have a datasource layer and a repository layer.

The repository uses an interface to interact with the underlying data sources (only an sql db atm), however the datasource interface is tailored for sql databases as shown here:

```
package datasource

import "database/sql"

type Source interface {
  Open() error                                        // Open the connection

  Close()                                             // Close the connection
      
  Exec(string, ...interface{}) error                  // Execute a prepared query(e.g:insert)

  Query(string, ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)    // Retrieve rows with a prepared query
}
```

As I imagine that other data sources will be introduced later on (like nosql dbs or external APIs...), how can I group them all under a common interface so that the repository doesn't need to be aware of the source of the data.

Thank you.

**P.S:** I know there are similar questions but those deal with the problem from the repository point of view, I'm looking for a solution from the datasource side (e.g: a common interface) as I don't want a seperate repository for each source.

Comment: Do you want something similar to [Object-Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)? It seems you want to avoid writing raw queries directly in the repositories, so you want one more level of abstraction. The common way for that is designing schema (data model), queries and connection abstractions. Take ORM implementations as reference.

Comment: @hldev Not exactly, It doesn't matter if I write raw queries or not, I just imagined that when I switch the data source used by the repository (e.g from mysql to rest api) I wouldn't need to modify the repository layer, instead I would just inject the new source into the repository. But as icza noted I guess I would need an independant query language and parsers to achieve this

Comment: If you needed to change repository when changing source, then you wrote raw queries in the repository. For example, when changing from MySQL to REST) you will need to replace SQL queries to HTTP queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your chosen abstraction level does not support database-neutral implementations. You are expecting SQL queries, and you are returning `*sql.Rows`.

If you want to be database-independent (including relational and NoSQL databases), you need to use a higher abstraction level where terms such as SQL or NoSQL queries do not exist.

For example if you intend to query, load and save users, the relevant part of your interface may look like this:

```
type User struct {
    ID string
    // other info about users
}

type Source interface {
    GetUser(id string) (*User, error)
    SaveUser(u *User) error
    FindUsersByFirstName(firstName string) ([]*User, error)
}
```

This interface does not restrict implementations to work with SQL queries and related objects, yet it expresses what operations you'll need. Other parts of your app should (must) access the data layer only via this interface. All the details (e.g. SQL queries) belong to the implementation.

Also before you go ahead with this abstraction, vet the advantages and extra work it requires, because often people plan for highly unlikely scenarios. If you start off with an SQL database, you will likely never switch to a NoSQL database.

You cannot (should not) have a single datasource layer that supports all databases at the abstraction level you want to. That would require to "develop" a database-independent query language and a parser to it, which you would then need to translate to specific database queries. If you want to support all databases, easiest is to merge the repository and datasource layers. Or give up supporting all databases as almost 99% of projects never switch to a database that is fundamentally different.

Comment: You are correct that my abstraction only support  sql dbs for now, however, what you described is the repository layer which already exists in my architecture (it's used  by the usecase layer), as stated in y question the repository will call the datasource layer to achieve its needs. In essence,my question was how to group the data sources under an abstraction so that the implementation of repository wouldnt be aware of the source details be it sql, nosql, some apis, etc...

Comment: @LonelyDaoist One `interface` can have multiple _implementations_, interfaces tells what objects _must do_, the _how_ is not relevant. Your `UseCase` does not want to talk to database, it wants the data. Each query will be mapped to a repository method, as exemplified by the great answer of @icza. If the UseCase wants to search users by name, then it will call `source.getUserByName('foo')` for a user 'foo'. Each implementation is a way, a _how_, to get the that required data. You will have `MongoDBSource implements Source`, `MySQLSource implements Source`, `CacheSource implements Source`, etc.

Comment: @LonelyDaoist your `UseCase` is aware of the interface, not the implementations. The variable type referenced by the `UseCase` is `Source`, not `MySQLSource`, `CacheSource` or `MongoDBSource`.

Comment: @hldev I am well aware what an interface is and how different layers interact with each others. My question doesn't touch usecase layer in any way, also the source and repository are different layers (in my case atleast). Again, my question was how to make one general/common abstraction aka interface that would be able to support many data sources be it sql db, nosql, cache or rest apis, I never mentioned any implementation whatsoever. Cheers.

Comment: @LonelyDaoist Generally a `Repository` is _the_ data source abstraction for a given type of data. You want a generic enough repository that allows one to build complex queries against different kinds of data sources and data types. @icza answered it, you will need to implement a generic [DDL, DQL and DML](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ddl-dql-dml-dcl-tcl-commands/)